# Pythonic way to solve a text normalization task

Tags: python, algorithm, text-processing

Basically, I have a Hive script file, from which I need to extract the names for all the tables created. For example, from the contents

```
...
create table Sales ...
...
create external table Persons ...
...
```

`Sales` and `Persons` should be extracted. To accomplish this, my basic idea is like:

1. Search for key phrases `create table` and `create external table`,
2. Extract the next token which should be the table name.

However, the input may not be canonical. For example,

1. Tab/newline may be used along with space as token delimiter
2. There may be multiple consecutive delimiters between tokens
3. Mixed use of upper and lower case letters like `create TABLE`

Therefore, I'm thinking about first normalizing the input to a canonical form before applying the basic algorithm. Then with some effort, I come up with the following

```
' '.join(input.split()).lower()
```

As a Python newcomer, I'm wondering whether this is the Pythonic way to solve the problem, or it may be flawed in the very first place? Is there a simple way to do this in a streaming fashion, i.e., avoiding loading the whole input into memory at once?

Comment: Sounds like a task for regular expressions.

Comment: Looks like you could use `regex`. It handles case insensitive matching, optional capture groups, and multiple spaces.

Comment: @KlausD. I think regular expression may be overkill here. Besides, could you show some code?

Comment: It is usually expected from the asker to show his/her code. (more than a very generic line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like some comments stated, regex is a neat and easy way to get what you want. If you don't mind getting lowercase results, this one should work:

```
import re
my_str = """
...
create table Sales ...
create TabLE  
 test
create external table Persons ...
...
"""
pattern = r"table\s+(\w+)\b"
items = re.findall(pattern, my_str.lower())
print items
```

It captures the next word after "table   " (followed by at least one whitespace / newline).

To get the original case of the table names:

```
for x, item in enumerate(items):
    i = my_str.lower().index(item)
    items[x] = my_str[i:i+len(item)]
print items
```